# Databricks delta table data changes based on query (superposition of data?)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, delta-lake

I have data stored in a Databricks SparkSQL Delta table with some columns as arrays of structs.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
    id_col bigint 
    ,primitive_col_A string 
    ,array_of_structs_col_B array<struct<field_A:string, field_B:string>>   
    ,array_of_structs_col_C array<struct<field_C:string, unique_field:string>>
  )
  USING DELTA LOCATION '/path/to/delta';
```

For some rows, it seems there are other values for the row for some columns, which can only be seen if I filter the query slightly.

As an example, I might do this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE t.id = 123 -- AKA Result_1
```

Which results in something like this:

| id_col | primitive_col_A | array_of_structs_col_B | array_of_structs_col_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | val_A | [{"field_A": "11", "field_B": "abc"}] | [{"field_C": "22", "unique_field": "44"}] |

But if I filter like this a get a different result for the array of structs:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE t.id = '123' -- AKA Result_2
```

| id_col | primitive_col_A | array_of_structs_col_B | array_of_structs_col_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | val_A | [{"field_A": "32", "field_C": "rtx"},{"field_A": "ty", "field_C": "jj"}] | [{"field_C": "67", "unique_field": "17"}] |

Also, filtering by a unique field inside in one of the structs of the arrays it will return a different `id_col` value.

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table t 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(t.array_of_structs_col_C.unique_field, 44) -- AKA Result_3
```

| id_col | primitive_col_A | array_of_structs_col_B | array_of_structs_col_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 456 | val_X | [] | [{"field_C": "36", "unique_field": "44"}] |

I have also tried including both filters with an `OR` operator but only one of the results is returned (even swapping the order):

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE t.id = 123 OR t.id = '123' -- AKA Result_2
```

| id_col | primitive_col_A | array_of_structs_col_B | array_of_structs_col_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | val_A | [{"field_A": "32", "field_C": "rtx"},{"field_A": "ty", "field_C": "jj"}] | [{"field_C": "67", "unique_field": "17"}] |

Other attempts include:

- Casting the id column to a string while filtering
- Casting the `array<struct<>>` fields as strings with the `to_json()` function
- Using `LIKE` instead of `=` also returns different results